# How i can use AccounterLive java Project on my Server Tomcat?

Tags: java, api, tomcat, integration

i want to know how to run AccounterLive java project on my server?

there are no documentation (yet!) and i already tried to run using tomcat but it is not working.

project URL is: https://github.com/vimukti/accounter

WebSite is: https://www.accounterlive.com/

i hope to get idea how to run this project on my tomcat.
the documentation says
May be you do not need a guide to run a java project :smiley: Though we will add a guide soon.